# for aws serverless, If I want to upload picture to endpoint, How to get the name of picture file?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I have image file upload endpoint on aws lambda, How to get the name of imagefile?

I use typescript to develop serverless aws lambda function like:

```
const upload: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event, context) => {
   ...
}
```

but I find the event only contains body for image contents. but no image file name.

How to get image file name?

Comment: The client should also send the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the image is being sent by the client as a multipart form-data you can use the  `parse-multipart` module as follows:

```
async function handlePost(event) {

  var contentType = event.headers["Content-Type"] || event.headers["content-type"]

  var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64')

  var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, multipart.getBoundary(contentType))

  for (var image of parts) {
     // Here the file name is accessible using image.filename 
  }

  ...

}
```

The `event` parameter is exactly the same received by your lambda in the first place.

Comment: Can you told me for multipart.Parse, what is the header? or import multipart from what libs?

Comment: multipart is an instance of this lib: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart)